"compileDebugJavaWithJavac" Gradle task assembleDebug failed
I'm trying to build my Flutter project after changing
Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 3
Flutter version 3.24.5
Dart version 3.5.4
DevTools version 2.37.3
Android SDK version 34.0.0
Platform android-34,
build-tools 34.0.0
gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
After the update:
create new flutter project without adding any packages in pubspec.yaml
build successfully.
when I try to add
pubspec.yaml
url_launcher: ^6.3.1
shared_preferences: ^2.3.3,
I am facing this issues

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone16k x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML
versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered.
This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-> line tools that were released at different times.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task >':url_launcher_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Could not determine the dependencies of null.
Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value
available.



BUILD FAILED in 31s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

For reference git code:
https://github.com/rdinesh19/sample12.git

I hope you add packages using this command:
flutter pub add <package_name>

If so, try these as well:
Update your settings.gradle file:

plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.7.0' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.7.0' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '2.0.20' apply false }

Update your gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file:
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip

Perform these commands in your terminal:
flutter pub get
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair

Note: flutter pub cache repair is optional, but if you find it necessary, execute this as well.
Then rebuild your project again.
I hope it helps!
